# Use same View and Partial in Two tabs, which change bases on Original or Amendment

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking to implement a Tab Menu that uses the same View and Partial View. But then when you click either of the tabs its updated based on the comparison in the Model. The Controller works out if its an Original or Amendment. So far I have the two tabs showing using:

```
var fullAccountCodeOriginal = Model.OriginalWriter.ID;
var fullAccountCodeAmendment = Model.ActiveAmendmentWriter.ID;

<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class='@((actionName.ToLower() == "viewwriteramendments") &&
           controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewWriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new
            {
                accountcode = fullAccountCodeOriginal
            })' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Song Management">Original Track Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class='@((actionName.ToLower() == "viewwriteramendments") &&
              controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewWriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new
            {
                accountcode = fullAccountCodeAmendment
            })' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Song Management">Updated Track Details</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

**In the Model is have:**

```
public ViewWriterAmendmentsComparisonModel()
    {
        this.OriginalWriter = default(WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel);
        this.ActiveAmendmentWriter = default(WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel);
    }

    public WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel OriginalWriter { get; set; }
    public WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel ActiveAmendmentWriter { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
 var writerAndActiveAmendment = new ViewWriterAmendmentsComparisonModel
        {
            OriginalWriter = new WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel
            {
                ID = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.ID,
                RowVersion = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.RowVersion,
                IsDeleted = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.IsDeleted,
                IsLocked = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.IsLocked,
                IsNew = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.IsNew,
                Version = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.Version,
                FirstName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.FirstName,
                MiddleName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.MiddleName,
                LastName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.LastName,
                PRO = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.Society?.Name ?? string.Empty,
                CaeIpiNumber = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.CaeIpiNumber,
                IsProMember = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.IsProMember,

                Songs = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.WriterSplits != null
                    ? domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.Original.WriterSplits
                        .Select(x => new AssociatedSongsComparisonModel
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            SongTitle = x.RelatedWork.Title,
                            SongId = x.RelatedWork.UniqueCode,
                            CreatedDate = x.RelatedWork.CreatedDate,
                            WriterCount = x.RelatedWork.WorkSplits.Count,
                            RecordingCount = x.RelatedWork.Recordings.Count
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<AssociatedSongsComparisonModel>(),
            },
            ActiveAmendmentWriter = new WriterAmendmentsComparisionModel
            {
                ID = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.ID,
                RowVersion = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.RowVersion,
                IsDeleted = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.IsDeleted,
                IsNew = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.IsNew,
                FirstName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.FirstName,
                MiddleName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.MiddleName,
                LastName = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.LastName,
                PRO = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.Society?.Name ?? string.Empty,
                CaeIpiNumber = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.CaeIpiNumber,
                IsProMember = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.IsProMember,

                Songs = domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.WriterSplitAmendments != null
                    && domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.WriterSplitAmendments.Any(x => x.RelatedWorkAmendment != null)
                    ? domainWriterAndAmendmentModel.CurrentAmendment.WriterSplitAmendments
                        .Select(x => new AssociatedSongsComparisonModel
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            SongId = x.RelatedWorkAmendment.UniqueCode,
                            SongTitle = x.RelatedWorkAmendment.Title,
                            CreatedDate = x.RelatedWorkAmendment.CreatedDate,
                            WriterCount = x.RelatedWorkAmendment.WorkSplitAmendments.Count,
                            RecordingCount = x.RelatedWorkAmendment.RecordingAmendments.Count
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<AssociatedSongsComparisonModel>(),
            }
        };
        return writerAndActiveAmendment;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ViewWriterAmendments")]
    [Route("{writercode}/ViewWriterAmendments")]
    [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult>ViewWriterAmendments(string writercode, int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage, string sortBy = "Name", bool sortAsc = true)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["IsAmendment"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.IsAmendment = Request.QueryString["IsAmendment"];
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.IsAmendment = "0";
        }

        // TEST IF VALID
        // ajax method - refuse
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("WriterAmendments", "SongsManagement");
        }

        // no writer - refuse
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(writercode))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("WriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { page, take, sortBy, sortAsc });
        }

        // get originalWithPossibleActiveAmendment work
        var writerAndAmendment = await _artistAccountService.GetWriterAndAmendmentGraphAsync(writercode, includeWritersSplitsAndWorks: true, includeWriterSociety: true);
        // not found? - refuse
        if (writerAndAmendment.Original == default(WriterGraph.Writer))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("WriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { page, take, sortBy, sortAsc });     // something wrong
        }
        // writer locked? - refuse
        if (writerAndAmendment.Original.IsLocked)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("WriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { page, take, sortBy, sortAsc });     // something wrong
        }

        // setup view model
        var viewModel = MapWriterAndAmendmentToViewModel(writerAndAmendment);

        // return view
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way I can get it switch betwwen the two tabs using JQuery or another method, maybe an IF/ELSE in Razor. I am new to MVC.

Comment: Dave check my answer, if you got any more questions ask in Comment, if I helped you please upvote and mark as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery so in Controller you got for example Enum param (if more than 2 cases of data loading) or boolean flag, which content to load. Than based on the parameter you've received you make an if statement inside controller to decide what data you should load. It's pretty simple, I won't give you fish but a rod. Read about overriding in jQuery button on click event and sending ajax requests.

Extra advice. IMHO this looks horrible

```
<li class='@((actionName.ToLower() == "viewwriteramendments") &&
          controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
    <a href='@Url.Action("ViewWriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new
        {
            accountcode = fullAccountCodeAmendment
        })' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Song Management">Updated Track Details</a>
</li>
```

1. Passing active class should be done inside jQuery too.
2. If you create repeatable li elements you could think about making another partial view for them. For 2 it's fine but for more elements create seperate view.
3. Change the a href to some button and override it's default behavior.
4. Naming conventions - try to name your ids and classes with some stable convention for whole project.

Comment: Thanks for that. The Tab Menu is in a separate partial. Would you be able to give me an example of what you mean using JQuery?